# jQuery act on HTML elements with display:none in Twitter Bootstrap Nav Dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I've spent the last few days banging my head and searching Google and have not found an acceptable solution to this.
I am using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) to code a new site.  We are using the Nav class and the built in drop down functionality, but instead of the standard single column dropdown, we would like a multi-column dropdown (we have lots of categories and subcategories that we would like to display in the dropdown and want to keep it all on the screen, without the dropdown getting super long and having to scroll).
To dynamically columnize the data (which is in a `<ul>`) I am using  [jquery.columnizer.js](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) which is great.

The problem is this:
Since the dropdown is hidden (via `display:none`) jQuery can't get the dimensions of the dropdown container. Since it can't get the dimensions, the columnizer can't columnize.

I've tried attaching the columnize function to a click event on the nav item, which doesn't work on the first click (if you toggle the menu on and off it works on subsequent toggles).

I don't want to modify the Bootstrap Javascript and there doesn't appear to be anything in columnizer that I can make work.
So, how can we get the columnize function (i.e.`$('.myNavElements').columnize();`) to trigger after the Bootstrap dropdown as been displayed?

**EDIT**:
Based on the accepted answer, the solution that worked for was this:

```
$(".dropdown").addClass("open");  
$('.dropdown-menu').columnize();  
$('.dropdown').removeClass("open");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the display to `block`, do stuff with it, then set it back to `none`. Because JavaScript is single-threaded, the browser will not redraw until the script is complete. Therefore it will not have a chance to draw the element as `block` before you set it back to `none`.

Comment: That worked! Bootstrap applies the "open" class to the dropdown parent to show and hide the menu.  To get this to work i had to apply and then remove the class. Please see the edited to for the simple, 3 line solution.